# How to fix a JavaScript plugin only working every other partial page ajax load

Tags: javascript, c#, html, model-view-controller

My problem is that the bootstrap toggle plugin only works every other time.

I'm using bootstrap-toggle to provide better styling to my checkboxes.

```
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
```

I'm using these in a partial view that is returned when an ajax call is made.

This is an example of my implementation:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Active, "", new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "Active", data_toggle = "toggle", data_width = "100%", data_on = "Active", data_off = "Disabled" }})
```

On the first load of the view when I click on the toggle it switches to the other value. If I close the window that the view has loaded in without refreshing the page, reopen the window and click on the toggle, nothing happens.

Edit: I should also mention that if I close the window that the view has loaded in Again without refreshing the page, reopen the window and click on the toggle it works. The issue isn't that it only works on the initial load but that it is working 50% of the time.

Comment: Because bootstrap will not know that you have refreshed page, you need to tell it to reinitialize

Comment: Sorry, could you expand on this? I'm not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: When you are calling ajax and reloading the div with your partial view at that time you need to reinitialize your check-boxes, to let bootstrap know there are new elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the script setups itself on the elements of your web page **only once**, which happens **right after the page is loaded**. After that, whenever you load new DOM elements (such as what happens when you reload a partial view through AJAX), the script doesn't execute its setup routine in the newly loaded elements.

After you load new elements via AJAX, you should perform a JavaScript call to `bootstrapToggle()` (checkout [Bootstrap Toggle's API](http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/#api)) on the newly loaded elements, so that the Bootstrap Toggle plugin could be activated for the newly loaded elements.

You should call something like this right after the new AJAX elements get loaded on the page:

```
// Replace by a selector which selects the elements which have been created
$('#myNewLoadedCheckboxElement').bootstrapToggle();
```

Comment: This is it! I added $('#Active').bootstrapToggle(); to the onSuccess of the Ajax call and now it works every time. Thanks!